# What is this low-growing evergreen?

Tags: identification, broad-leaved-evergreens

[image]

I found this plant in my woods And would like the identification. It is a small woody evergreen that grows in dry soil in light to deep shade. It grows about 1 1/2' tall and has small clusters of small greenish white flowers terminally on new wood in summer.[image]

Update pic: I replanted it in a lighter location, and the plant has shot up to about 3 1/2 feet, after I topped it off.

[image]

Comment: Do the leaves turn completely red? Do you have pictures of flowers? Or at least can you draw the basic shape? It will help a lot. I think too that it is _Euonymus_ spp. because I have seen pink buds and leaves with redish tints in this species.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think this might be [wintercreeper or euonymus](http://www.nps.gov/plants/alien/pubs/midatlantic/eufo.htm).  Although it is native to China it has naturalized in many parts of the eastern United States.  The leaves have light coloured veins, it is a creeper, evergreen and adaptable to a wide variety of soils.

It is this adaptable part of it's nature that leads to the recommendations to remove it as it it considered invasive and displaces native vegetation.

The most definitive identification is the pink round capsules that open to show red-orange arils (seeds).

Comment: The reddish foliage and pink buds are new to me - have you seen a euonymus with that before?

Comment: No I haven't, but there are so many varieties of euonymus.  I cannot determine if the pink buds are new leaf buds or flowers.  So I'm back to thinking it might be...

Comment: Pretty sure this isn't it. It has grown to almost three feet high.

Comment: @J.Musser _Euonymus fortunei_ (Turcz.) Hand.-Mazz. cv. Coloratus. > http://www.arboretum.org.msstate.edu/euonfort.htm

Comment: @ondoteam See update pic in question.

Comment: @J.Musser your picture is really small but I think it is. Check it http://www.onlineplantguide.com/Image%20Library/E/3355.jpg

Comment: @ondoteam Okay, that one matches.

Comment: The linked picture is from a Euonymus fortunei (Turcz.) Hand.-Mazz.